# PostgreSQL: Crear un trigger para capturar valores de una Insert

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, trigger

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos PostgreSQL.

Tengo una tabla llamada valores_controladores a la que automáticamente le llegan valores de unos controladores.

A parte de esa tabla, tengo otra tabla llamada alarmas_saltadas.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se introduzca una fila en la tabla valores_controladores, leer un campo y determinando si es superior a 100 ó inferior a 10 introducir valores en la tabla alarmas_saltadas.

Gracias de Antemano

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes que crear un trigger before insert on valores_controladores y luego en tu función asociada pones la condición de si es superior a 100 o inferiro a 10 y si se cumple lo insertas en alarmas_saltadas. El código sería más menos así:

```
Create function f1() returns trigger as
$$
declare
begin 
if new.campo > 100 or new.campo < 10 then
insert into alarmas_saltadas values (val1, val2, ....);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;

Create trigger t1 before insert on valores_controladores for each row execute procedure f1();
```